# Point free programming style in haskell (ghci)

Tags: haskell, pointfree

I came across a snippet of code for computing combinations in haskell, and I thought I'll play with it in ghci to understand how it works. In ghci when I run just the bit of code that I'm interested in it fails as shown below.

```
Prelude Data.List> filter ((== 2) . length) . subsequences [1,2,3]

<interactive>:19:1:
    No instance for (Show ([a0] -> [[a0]]))
      arising from a use of ‘print’
    In a stmt of an interactive GHCi command: print it
Prelude Data.List> filter ((== 2) . length) . subsequences [1,2,3]

<interactive>:20:28:
    Couldn't match expected type ‘a -> [[a1]]’
                with actual type ‘[[a0]]’
    Relevant bindings include
      it :: a -> [[a1]] (bound at <interactive>:20:1)
    Possible cause: ‘subsequences’ is applied to too many arguments
    In the second argument of ‘(.)’, namely ‘subsequences [1, 2, 3]’
    In the expression:
      filter ((== 2) . length) . subsequences [1, 2, 3]
```

I knew it had to be because of the composition(dot) operator. In ghci I had to change it to use "$" sign to run that code as shown below

```
Prelude Data.List> filter ((== 2) . length) $ subsequences [1,2,3]
[[1,2],[1,3],[2,3]]
```

Could someone explain a bit about what is going on internally when you write code in this programming style(pointfree) please? And why ghci fails when I use that expression directly?

Comment: *In ghci I had to change it* - show the original code in its original form.

Answer (score 9):

It's just a matter of operator precedence. Your code is being read as

```
(filter ((== 2) . length))    .     (subsequences [1,2,3])
```

and then GHCi complains that `subsequences [1,2,3]` is not a function. So, you need parentheses:

```
(filter ((== 2) . length) . subsequences) [1,2,3]
```

or `$`:

```
filter ((== 2) . length) . subsequences $ [1,2,3]
```